# Custom 404 page Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to redirect from an unknown path written down by a user to a custom 404 page:

For example:

/login goes to login page

/main goes to main page

{unknown-path} goes to 404

```
    export const deepLinkConfig: DeepLinkConfig = {
links: [
{ component: HomePage, name: "Home", segment: "" },
{ component: LoginPage, name: "Login", segment: "login", defaultHistory: [HomePage] },
{ component: SubscribePage, name: "Signup", segment: "signup", defaultHistory: [HomePage] },
{ component: SubscribeExtendPage, name: "Signup", segment: "signup-extend", defaultHistory: [HomePage] },
{ component: MainPage, name: "Main", segment: "main", defaultHistory: [HomePage] },
{ component: WelcomePage, name: "Welcome", segment: "welcome" },
{ component: NotFoundPage, name: "notFound", segment: "login/**", defaultHistory: [NotFoundPage] },
]
};


imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpClientModule,
MaterializeModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, deepLinkConfig)
],
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ component: NotFoundPage, name: "*", segment: ":**", defaultHistory: [NotFoundPage] },
```

I don't know if it is the best solution but finally worked setting the segment with a variable of any kind, :** and now all the unknown url are redirected to NotFoundPage.

Comment: **ATTENTION**, this method cause another issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305260/ionic-3-add-a-404-page-to-url-router) and also some troubles with direct access at `/#/`