# Ionic 3 - add a 404 page to URL Router

Tags: angular, url, ionic-framework, parameters, routes

In this Question I found a answer for 404 pages in Ionic 3 Routing:
[Custom 404 page Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770024/custom-404-page-ionic-3)

But I have a problem in my router when I use parameters. If I add this to my router:

```
{ component: EventdetailsPage, name: 'Details', segment: 'event/:eventId',defaultHistory: [HomePage] },
```

With this line at the bottom of my config, every call to a page with parameters will redirected:

```
{ component: NotFoundPage, name: "*", segment: ":**", defaultHistory: [NotFoundPage] },
```

on every call of .../event/123 it will redirect me to the 404 page. I tried a lot of combinations like -> segment: ":**"/":**"

but nothing works. Where can I find a 404 page solution that works with PWA Urls in Ionic.

Comment: I'm looking forward for the same answer...